# How to use Python string formatting to convert an integer representing cents to a float representing dollars?

Tags: python, django-templates, string-formatting, currency

I have an integer representing a price in cents.  Using Python format strings, how can I convert this value into dollars with two decimal places?  Examples:

```
1234 => 12.34
5 => 0.05
999 => 9.99
```

EDIT: I should give some background.  I am storing prices in a database as integers in order to make sure I don't loose precision.  I don't want to use the Decimal datatype because these values will also be used in calculations in Javascript, so integers will be simplest to work with for that.  I want to be able to display in a Django template the formatted value using the stringformat tag.  As such, dividing the number by 100 doesn't work.  Is there a way to add the decimal point without dividing?

Comment: Don't use float for currency.  It's utterly wrong.  Decimal works perfectly for your needs.  It can be converted to a string (for Javascript) and all financial calculations work correctly with decimal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try hard to avoid ever using floats to represent money (numerical inaccuracy can too easily creep in). The decimal module provides a useful datatype for representing money as it can exactly represent decimal numbers such as 0.05.

It can be used like this:

```
import decimal
cents = 999
dollars = decimal.Decimal(cents) / 100
print dollars
```

Comment: This doesn't work for various numbers like 0 cents (returns 0), 10 cents (returns 0.1), etc.

Answer (score 7):

Using [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
for i in (1234,5,999):
    print('{:.2f}'.format(i/100.))
```

yields

```
12.34
0.05
9.99
```

In Python2.6 use `'{0:.2f}'` instead of `'{:.2f}'`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about localization, then simply divide by 100 and format it:

```
>>> for cents in [ 1234, 5, 999 ]:
...     '{0:.02f}'.format(float(cents) / 100.0)
...
'12.34'
'0.05'
'9.99'
```

If you do care about localization, then use the [`locale`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#module-locale) module:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "") # use the user-default locale
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> for cents in [ 1234, 5, 999 ]:
...     locale.currency(float(cents) / 100.0)
...
'$12.34'
'$0.05'
'$9.99'
```

Comment: I'm not sure that working with `floats` and currency is a good idea.